# JBehave - loading stories from an external folder

Tags: jbehave

We have to load all stories from an external folder, where stories exist in the root external folder and inside subfolders.  JUnit-runnable entry-point is used to run the stories (a class which extends JUnitStories class) . How I should implement storyPaths method , I'tried with codeLocationsFromUrl, codeLocationsFromPath but JBehave was not able to locate stories in both cases.

Comment: Under a default Maven setup, JBehave expects to look for story files somewhere under target/test-classes which is created while the test is being run.  I take it your story files are outside of the standard src/test/java folder setup?  It doesn't matter how deep it is, but I believe it MUST be under your src\ folder.  You can pass a partial sub-folder sequence to the storyfinder, like "**\\storyfiles\\\*.story"  I believe you can also override where maven looks for resources, which might help.  I don't know the exact syntax on that, however.

Comment: Thanks Bill but something is very wrong here. BDD tool should be shared between analysts and developers , I can not tell analyst to find the latest Jenkins build than translate that to file path then from that path go to relative path (src/test/whatever) and update examples section and run Jenkins job again, it doesn't have sense.

Comment: Perhaps you could use examples tables instead of hard-coding them into the stories?  This way, the location of the story files is irrelevant to the analysts and you can instead locate your example table files in another folder, referenced by the story files themselves.